# Using gdalwarp to change raster extent, float value issue (Python 2.7, GDAL)

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, gdalwarp, extents

I am trying to change the extent of a rasterized shapefile to match that of another raster so it can act as a mask for the latter. Other posts suggest using gdalwarp. However, when using gdalwarp to create a new output it throws me a TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. Is gdalwarp unable to use float values? Although I can't see this written anywhere as a limitation of the function. Below is my code:

```
slope_src = r'C:\data\extraction\slope.tif'
mask_src = r'C:\data\buildings\blds.tif'
mask_new = r'C:\data\buildings\blds_mask.tif'
slope_raster = gdal.Open(slope_src)
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres = slope_raster.GetGeoTransform()
xres = 0.4
yres = 0.4
lrx = ulx + (slope_raster.RasterXSize * xres)
lry = uly + (slope_raster.RasterYSize * yres)
subprocess.call(["C:\\PRogram Files\\GRASS GIS 7.3\\extrabin\\gdalwarp.exe", "-te", lrx, lry, ulx, uly, mask_src, mask_new])
```

Comment: It seems to me you have wrong order in te key (-te xmin ymin xmax ymax). ulx == xmin, lrx == xmax, lry == ymin, uly == ymax.  Try to swap x in your command line like this: subprocess.call(["C:\\PRogram Files\\GRASS GIS 7.3\\extrabin\\gdalwarp.exe", "-te", ulx, lry, lrx, uly, mask_src, mask_new])

Comment: This removed the error, but now the issue is that 'mask_new' is not created by gdalwarp.

Comment: From your code I don't understand the sense of using gdalwarp. To extract part of the image the gdal_translate with -projwin ulx uly lrx lry key are applicable. gdalwarp is for reprojecting from one SRS to another or for reference based on GCP.

Comment: With the use of '.SetGeoTransform()' I was able to match the extents of the rasterized shapefile by passing it with the results of '.GetGeoTransform() applied to the raster to be masked.